# Convert columns to rows

Tags: mysql, row

I have a table with 2 columns, the first shows the question then the second shows the answer

It looks like this

```
Question | Answer
    Q1   |  Ans1
    Q2   |  Ans2
    Q3   |  Ans3
```

I want it to look like this

```
Q1
Ans1

Q2
Ans2

Q3
Ans3
```

How's the best way to do this?

Here's the sample data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cef08/2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you are looking for this. Anyway, following query works finely.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT('Q:', q_id, ':1') AS orders, question
    FROM question WHERE q_id IN (1, 2, 3)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CONCAT('Q:', q_id, ':2') AS orders, answer
    FROM answer WHERE q_id IN (1, 2, 3)
) x
ORDER BY orders;

+--------+----------+
| orders | question |
+--------+----------+
| Q:1:1  | Q1       |
| Q:1:2  | Ans1     |
| Q:2:1  | Q2       |
| Q:2:2  | Ans2     |
| Q:3:1  | Q3       |
| Q:3:2  | Ans3     |
+--------+----------+
```

Please, **be aware that** I think your JOIN query in sqlfiddle is better than this UNION, if query results can be converted by client side.